Can I put PS5 into rest mode using python code as the PS5 and my PC is on the same wifi/network
I am trying to develop a web app that I can monitor the usage of PS5.
I tried to work with this code:
Import requests

ps5_ip = "192.168.1.100"
url = f"http://{ps5_ip}/rest_mode"

response = requests.post(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("PS5 is being put into rest mode.")
else:
    print("Failed to put PS5 into rest mode.")

But it keeps saying:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I tried several codes but no use.
